How to show InstanceName along with Instance ID in Grafana (Cloudwatch datasource)
I am using grafana with cloudwatch datasource.
The legend of the line graph when querying metrics like cpuutilization (filtered by instanceID =*) only shows instanceID. It will be useful to show InstanceName as well.
I have gone through this https://github.com/grafana/grafana/pull/8307. However looks like the {{InstanceName}} in alias used to work. But this returns nothing for me.
Can anyone suggest a workaround or solution for this?

It seems absolutely insane to me, but apparently, this is not possible. I've searched everywhere.
